# Spring Boot MongoDB findTop5 returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and MongoDB for a personal project to create a movie and video game database. I have methods that retrieve the latest five entries of each category. When I was testing on a local Tomcat and MongoDB server, the methods work as expected. However, when I deploy to a tomcat server and connect to a MongoDB server, the methods that retrieve the latest five entries always return an empty array.  here is the code:

Repository:

```
public interface MovieRepository extends MongoRepository<Movies, String>{
    public List<Movies> findAllByOrderByTitleAsc(Pageable pageable);

    @Query("{'title': {$regex: ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
    public List<Movies> findByTitle(String title);

    public List<Movies> findTop5ByCreatedAtLessThan(String currentDate);

    public Movies findMovieById(String id);

    public List<Movies> findByPlatformsIn(List<String> platforms);
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MovieController {
    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MapValidationErrorService mapValidationErrorService;
    @Autowired
    private CurrentDateService currentDateService;

    @GetMapping("/movies")
    public List<Movies> findAllMovies(@RequestParam(value="page",       defaultValue="0")int page) {
    return movieRepository.findAllByOrderByTitleAsc(PageRequest.of(page, 20));
    }

    @GetMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public Movies findMovieById(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {
        return movieRepository.findMovieById(movieId);
    }

    @PostMapping("/movies")
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveMovie(@Valid @RequestBody Movies movie, BindingResult result) {
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.mapvalidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        movie.setId(null);

        Movies newMovie = movieRepository.save(movie);

        return new ResponseEntity<Movies>(newMovie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/movies")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateMovie(@Valid @RequestBody Movies movie, BindingResult result) {
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = mapValidationErrorService.mapvalidationService(result);

        if (errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        Movies updatedMovie = movieRepository.save(movie);

        return new ResponseEntity<Movies>(updatedMovie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/movies/{movieId}")
    public void deleteMovieById(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {
        movieRepository.deleteById(movieId);
    }

    @GetMapping("/moviePlatforms")
    public List<Movies> findMoviesByPlatforms(@RequestParam(value="platform") List<String>platforms) {
        return movieRepository.findByPlatformsIn(platforms);
   }

    @GetMapping("/newFiveMovies")
    public List<Movies> findTop5ByCreatedAt() {
        String currentDate = currentDateService.getCurrentDate();

        return movieRepository.findByCreatedAt(currentDate);
    }
}
```

I have changed the find top 5 methods to use the @Query annotation, but it yields the same results. All the other methods in the controller and repository work as expected. I have tried using MongoDB on a Mac, and also on MongoDB Atlas. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any annotation on any of the `findTop5By` variants included in your question.  The only mapped method you are showing is `findTop5ByCreatedAt()` and that **needs** a `$lt` in the `@Query` annotation, otherwise it's looking for an "exact value", which of course is unlikely to ever happen.

Comment: I used the following for the annotation: `@Query("{'createdAt': {$lt: ?0}}")` and I renamed the method `findByCreatedAt`. Using that still returned an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the date I was sending as a parameter was formatted wrong. The date was being stored as "M/d/yy h:mm a", but I was sending "M/dd/yyyy hh:mm a".